# QML Calendar: wrong number of weeks displayed in a month view

Tags: javascript, calendar, qml

I am trying to figure out how to resize the calendar grid depending on the number of weeks each month has.
Currently it is defined as 6rows * 7columns grid, regardless of the number of weeks per month (if it has 4 or 5, it will still display 6 weeks). Even the picture from the documentation shows an extra week.

I was checking if there was a flag like: fixedWeekCount on QML but I cannot find anything to modify the grid to match with the weeks. Any tips?

[image: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-calendar.html]

Answer (score 1):

There's no public API for this, and I'm not sure if it's possible to do by implementing a custom style.

Showing 6 weeks is pretty standard for calendars, as it allows it to have a fixed size by accounting for differences between months. From the calendars that I checked (Windows 10, Android, calendar.google.com), only calendar.google.com had 5 weeks visible, and going from e.g. September to October would cause the rows to be resized, which does not really result in an intuitive, consistent user interface.

As @derM also pointed out, the greyed-out days from the prior and subsequent months are usually shortcuts to change the selected month, which is beneficial for the user.

Comment: Especially as the greyed-out days from the prior and subsequent month are usually shortcuts to change the selected month, which is beneficial for the user.

Comment: Right, I can see the benefits on having some days from the previous/next month in the calendar. But it is not a solution for what I want to achieve.